# CSS Directive calling incorrect class

Tags: html, css, svelte

I'm trying to make a collapsible sidebar menu, but currently it flickers open and closed on page reloads.

The problem code seems to be this CSS directive in the nav.

```
{on === true ? 'on' : 'off'}
```

I've tried changing the CSS directive a couple ways, but these only apply animations when the menu is opening. So I think I'm misunderstanding how the directives work.

```
class:on
on:click={() => on = !on}
{on ? "on":""}
```

Here's an example (the code in question is in the sidebar tab): https://svelte.dev/repl/df5d44d97e614945aa06c7a9d9b9038f

HTML:

```
<aside class="absolute w-full h-full bg-gray-200 border-r-2 shadow-lg mobile-menu {on === true ? 'on' : 'off'}">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="logo">
                <a href="/">GPM</a>
            </li>

            <hr />

            <li><a class="menu-items"href='.'>Index</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-items"href='about'>About</a></li>
        
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
.on {
    animation-name: slide-on;
    animation-duration: 0.3s; 
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    position: fixed;
}

@keyframes slide-on{
    0% {
        left: -100%;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    to{
        left: 0;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

.off {
    animation-name: slide-off;
    animation-duration: 0.3s; 
    animation-direction: normal; 
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@keyframes slide-off{
    0% {
        left: 0;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    99%{
        left: -99%;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100%{
        left: -100%;
        transform: scale(0);
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
export let on = false;
```

Comment: could you please also post your app on svelte.dev? that way we can test your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the other answer is correct in stating that the animation is playing because of the initial state of your component, it should be said that you can greatly simplify this code by using the built in transitions from Svelte.

In your script tag, import the fly transition

```js
import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';
```

wrap the entire sidebar with an if block to hide/show it completely

```html
{#if on}
  <aside>...</aside>
{/if}
```

and then apply the fly transition to your aside:

```html
<aside class="..." transition:fly={{x: -window.innerWidth }}>
```

And then there is no need for all those css classes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your sidebar component defaults with a class of 'off', which is causing the annimation to display.

I've made a solution here that only adds the 'off' class if the 'on' variable has ever been true. there is probably a better solution, but this works.

https://svelte.dev/repl/4afa7e650d1b41759426d7ad0998932f?version=3.37.0